# Cloud storage Denied Permission Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage, firebase-security

So I have added some security rules to my firebase storage when I use the simulation it works as expected but when I actually perform from my app it shows me this error

```
2021-04-09 16:43:00.322 17375-17375/com.margsapp.messenger E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
User does not have permission to access this object.
Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403

2021-04-09 16:43:00.323 17375-17375/com.margsapp.messenger E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session

Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
```

So I simplified the log cat

And this is my security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {

match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
}

match/ProfileImages/{userId}{      //Am trying to upload an image to this directory.
allow read: if request.auth != null;
allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
match/GroupImages{
allow read,write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

If the code which uploads image is necessary I will upload
If I done any mistake in rules please let me know the right way to do it.

EDIT: This is the code which uploads the image

```
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/ProfileImages/"+firebaseUser.getUid());

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(this);

    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we update your profile picture...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            assert result != null;
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(resultUri));


            uploadTask = filepath.putFile(resultUri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return filepath.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(edit_profile.this, "Image has been stored in our servers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        assert downloadUri != null;
                        String mUri = downloadUri.toString();


                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("imageURL", mUri);
                        reference.updateChildren(map);

                        loadingBar.dismiss();

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile Picture updation is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = edit_profile.this.getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that produces that error.

Comment: I have added the code which uploads to image and I have already added LogCat too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to match all paths within:

```
ProfileImages -> userId
```

In your Storage bucket. So your rules should look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read: if request.auth != null;
        }
        match /ProfileImages/{userId} {
            match /{allPaths=**} {
                allow read: if request.auth != null;
                allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have applied the rules but when I ran the simulation it denied access even authenticated with userid ones

Comment: It was only an example for `ProfileImages -> userId`. Please check again. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much it worked but I had to do a small change in your code to work you actually missed to mention rules version so when I added it worked as expected again Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Just updated my answer with the "rules_version = '2';".